# How to retain recycler view data and state after searchview query on configuration change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view and a search view. After i put a query and get the result in the recycler view, the query is cleared and the default recycler view is shown when configuration changes.

Video link of the problem i am facing - https://imgur.com/a/3Ea1tsp

Code -

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityAttendanceListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    window.statusBarColor = getColorFromAttribute(this,R.attr.colorSurfaceVariant)
    binding.obstructor.setBackgroundColor(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(getColorFromAttribute(this,R.attr.colorOnPrimary),235))

    binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

    arrayList = arrayListOf<AttendanceListRecyclerViewDataClass>()
    tempArrayList = arrayListOf<AttendanceListRecyclerViewDataClass>()
    
    recyclerViewAdapter = AttendanceListRecyclerViewAdapter(arrayList)
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter

    binding.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            if (dy > 0) binding.editFab.shrink() else if (dy < 0) binding.editFab.extend()
            if (dy > 0) binding.filterFab.hide() else if (dy < 0) binding.filterFab.show()
        }
    })
    if(binding.searchView.query.isNotEmpty()){
        activityViewModel.setQueryState(true)
        tempArrayList.forEach {
            if(it.Date!!.contains(binding.searchView.query)){
                arrayList.add(it)
            }
        }
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
            arrayList.clear()

            if(query!!.isEmpty()){
                activityViewModel.setQueryState(false)
                arrayList.addAll(tempArrayList)
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            if(query.isNotEmpty()){
                activityViewModel.setQueryState(true)
                tempArrayList.forEach {
                    if(it.Date!!.contains(query)){
                        arrayList.add(it)
                    }
                }
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            return false
        }

    })

    binding.obstructor.setOnClickListener {
        onEditButtonClicked()
    }

    binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
        getAttendanceData()
        binding.swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
    }

    getAttendanceData()

    binding.editFab.setOnClickListener {
        onEditButtonClicked()
    }
}

    private fun getAttendanceData() {
    arrayList.clear()
    tempArrayList.clear()
    db.collection("Attendance").get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { itAlt ->
            if (itAlt.isSuccessful){
                for(doc in itAlt.result!!){
                    val date = doc.data.getValue("Date").toString()
                    val tempAlt = ArrayList<String>()
                    tempAlt.addAll(doc.data.getValue("Time") as Collection<String>)
                    for(i in tempAlt){
                        db.collection("Attendance").document(date).collection(i).addSnapshotListener(object: EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
                            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                            override fun onEvent(
                                value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                                if(error != null){
                                    Toast.makeText(this@ActivityAttendanceList,"Firestore Error, ${error.message}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    return
                                }
                                for(dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){
                                    if(dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                                        arrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(AttendanceListRecyclerViewDataClass::class.java))
                                        tempArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(AttendanceListRecyclerViewDataClass::class.java))
                                    }
                                }
                                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Is there a way i can save the recycler view state and then restore it?
Let me know, if more info is required.

I tried implementing this by using view-model and then restoring the previous filtered array after configuration change, but then search query just doesn't work and the recycler view is stuck with the new filtered array list and doesn't change on query.

Comment: when user scroll recyclerview you should store first visible item position, you can get this position in onScrollListener of recyclerview and save it in viewmodel. Then when search is closed move your recycleview to that position

Comment: But won't that make recycler view obtain the original data and not the filtered one? I just want the filtered array data to remain after configuration change and not move the recycler view position to the first occurrence of the query in recycler view.